# Chain Backbone.js collection method

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

How can I chain collection methods in [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)?

```
var Collection = this.collection;
Collection = Collection.where({county: selected});
Collection = Collection.groupBy(function(city) {
  return city.get('city')
});
Collection.each(function(city) {
  // each items
});
```

I tried something like this, but it's wrong:

```
Object[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'groupBy'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot access `Backbone.Collection` methods that way (hope I'm not wrong) but as you probably know most of the Backbone methods are Underscore.js based methods so that means if you look at the the source code for [`where`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-94) method you will see it uses Underscore.js `filter` method, so this means you can achieve what you want doing so:

```
var filteredResults = this.collection.chain()
    .filter(function(model) { return model.get('county') == yourCounty; })
    .groupBy(function(model) { return model.get('city') })
    .each(function(model) { console.log(model); })
    .value();
```

`.value()` isn't of any use to you here, you are making "stuff" inside the `.each` method for each of the model but if you would like to let's say return an array of filtered cities you can do with `.map` and in `filteredResults` will be your results

```
var filteredResults = this.collection.chain()
    .filter(function(model) { return model.get('county') == yourCounty; })
    .map(function(model) { return model.get('city'); })
    .value();
console.log(filteredResults);
```